# Overview of Sharepoint 2010 and 2013 capabilities?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I'm looking for a page that provides a good, fairly basic and brief, end-user targeted overview of the capabilities of Sharepoint 2010, and another that does the same for Sharepoint 2013. I searched microsoft.com and couldn't really find much. Most of what I found was based on the assumption that the reader was familiar with Sharepoint already and was upgrading from an older version. I was hoping to find something for folks *new* to Sharepoint, checking it out for the very first time.  Something kind of like a product info sheet that you'd see in a trade show booth, maybe.

Any pointers to something along these lines would be appreciated.

Background:
I work for a large university, and we offer Google Apps, Box, and Sharepoint (2010 now, 2013 soon) as options to support collaborative projects.  I'm trying to help our user community understand the different capabilities of and optimal use cases for each tool.  I've found good overview material for Box and Google Apps, but I'm getting stuck finding this for Sharepoint.  And -- as luck would have it -- our users tend to be the *least* familiar with Sharepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often hard to find decent information about SharePoint on the internet.. ;)

Maybe some of these links will help, but most probably you have already seen them all:

- http://www.slideshare.net/pointbeyond/comparison-webinar3
- http://sharepointpromag.com/blog/sharepoint-2010-vs-sharepoint-2013-small-step-or-big-jump
- http://www.rharbridge.com/?page_id=966 [from a technical point of view]
- http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-server-2013/features/end-user/
- http://www.cmswire.com/cms/social-business/sharepoint-2013-social-features-highlights-019624.php
- http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint/sharepoint-2013-overview-collaboration-software-features-FX103789323.aspx [collaboration feature overview - and it's official! ;)]

JFYI: there are also a couple of frameworks and platforms available which improve the social capabilities, for example [MatchPoint Snow](http://www.colygon.com/matchpoint-snow/) is one I have heard of.

**Update:**

Ok, if you're willing to actually convince people to use SharePoint, try following query - I think there are some good results there (but maybe there also too tech-targeted): https://www.google.ch/#q=why%20should%20i%20use%20sharepoint

For example:

- http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/whitepaper/6-things-every-manager-should-know-about-microsoft-sharepoint
- http://www.degdigital.com/blog/why-sharepoint-2013-considerations-for-your-platform-selection/
- http://newsletter.stc-carolina.org/How+to+Encourage+Good+Use+of+SharePoint

Comment: some more information can be found here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303422(v=office.15).aspx and 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303422(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks to you both. This actually confirms what I had already seen: There seems to be a lot of material either targeted at IT professionals evaluating a Sharepoint purchase or upgrade; or at end-users who are being subjected to an upgrade from 2010 to 2013 by their IT folks.  But I can't really find anything that explains to an end user why he/she might want to choose to use Sharepoint in the first place. I know that we're unusual: In higher education it's impossible to compel people to use a particular solution, we have to convince them.  Still, I had hoped someone might have done so already.

Comment: I just updated my post with some new "convincing-links". I think convincing people into something new is always tough. Maybe some of the links help. Good luck anyway!

Comment: Thanks Pzyon.  It's looking increasingly like we'll have to build something on our own locally, but the sources you've provided will be incredibly helpful in putting that together, so I'll go ahead and mark your answer as correct.  Really appreciate your help!